# SQL - Find names and total budget associated with name

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table named `PROJECT` that looks something like this

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM PROJECT;

P#     PTITLE            SPONSOR                 D#   BUDGET
------ ----------------- ----------------------- ---- ----------
  1001 Computation       Microsoft                  1      25000
  1002 Study methods     Education committee        3      15000
  1003 Racing car        Cloud Pty Ltd              3     225000
  1004 Football          Football club              5      35000
  1005 Swimming          Education committee        5     125000
```

And from this table, I would like to list the name of sponsors, and the total budget that each sponsor provided.

I am working with Oracle SQL and am having some difficulty with the syntax to select the data from this table.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple aggregation should suffice

```
SELECT SPONSOR,SUM(BUDGET) 
FROM PROJECT 
GROUP BY SPONSOR
```

Comment: So much simpler than what I was trying out. Thanks heaps!